# Setting up a computer to act as an HID device connected to another computer via ps/2,usb or another wired connection

Tags: arduino, usb, hid, ps2

I’m interested in setting up a machine (host A) and connect it to another one (host B) via usb or ps/2 such that host B will recognise host A as a keyboard. On host A an artificial neuronal network is running which generates dynamically input sequences. It’s important to me that host A can only communicate to host B in a “human” way, e.g. generating keystrokes and passing them to host B.

As far as I know this is not possible with an usb connection since a host to host connection is not possible, further a ps/2 connection should be possible.

I know as well that an Arduino Uno or Leonardo can server as a USB HID keyboard, but since I’ve to program the device in advance it’s not useful to use them since it’s impossible to run the neuronal network on Arduino. 
Something like:

[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ua_5Uekg4tQ)

would be interesting as well, unfortunately it’s in Russian :(

However I’m not confined how to start and which starting point is suitable for my problem.

For that reason I’m grateful for any hint how to do this.