# Can a USB 3 Host machine be programmed as a USB 3 Peripheral (or a HID keyboard)?

Tags: keyboard, usb, artificial-intelligence, driver, hid

**What I want to do:**

An AI program on a host machine, reading inputs from a camera sensing the screen of the target machine and outputting controls to the target machine via USB connection--programming the host machine's USB host as a USB peripheral connected to the target machine.

**What I want to do step by step:** (is it possible to implement the steps below?)

1. Have a host machine A and a target machine B.
2. Connect A and B with a USB 3.0 Type-A male-male cable.
3. The USB connection shows up as an HID keyboard device on B.
4. Write code to simulate key presses on A that sends to B.
   (Eg. calling `press('F')` on a program running on A would type `F` to B's input)
5. It shouldn't require any program installed on B.

**What I already searched:**

1. USB 3.0 Host to host connection is possible:
   https://superuser.com/questions/795053/how-do-i-connect-two-computers-using-usb-3-0
2. USB 2.0 Host to host connection is impossible:
   https://superuser.com/questions/99274/how-to-connect-two-computers-with-usb
3. Similar questions asked without the assumption that USB 3.0 Host to Host connection is possible:

   - https://superuser.com/questions/1128365/simulate-usb-keyboard-from-machine
   - [Setting up a computer to act as an HID device connected to another computer via ps/2,usb or another wired connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386160/setting-up-a-computer-to-act-as-an-hid-device-connected-to-another-computer-via)
   - https://superuser.com/questions/507921/computer-to-act-as-keyboard?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions in ascending order of feasibility:

### USB Gadgets

You are using linux, so the default way would be to create/configure/load a gadget driver. Have a look [at this tutorial](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/raspberry-pi-zero-usb-keyboard-hid/), though for a raspberry, should work on your PC too. However, I could not find any information regarding the use of USB3 - the tutorial assumes your host is using one of it's OTG ports, which your PC most likely does not have. So whether this works with your USB3.1 Type-A-to-Type-A connection you'll need to test.

### USBIP

The idea of sharing USB devices (not just keyboards) [is not really new](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/). With USBIP you can "export" any local USB device to the network, and your client will need the client-side USBIP driver to access the keyboard.

### Dont bother with USB at all, just use Ethernet

I'd simply write two userland scripts/programs that send/receive+execute the keystrokes. Very easy to implement, you're probably familiar with python anyway.

---

*If you absolutely cant have software installed on the client-PC and your Type-C-to-Type-C connection doesnt support USB Gadgets, there's another way. It basically involves the use of two USB-to-serial adapters (~15$) and a serial cable. While this wont be enumerated as a keyboard, but rather as serial port, it's the lowest-effort solution to transfer data without additional software on the client. Both computers will just do file I/O. If your computers still have COM-ports, you can even omit the serial converters!*